# I want to plot in Rstudio viewer instead of in browser with plotly interaction plots

Tags: python, plotly, rstudio, viewer

⬆️

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(y=[2, 1, 3])],
    layout_title_text="A Figure Displayed with fig.show()"
)
fig.show()
```

Taking this for an example, the fig just show in the browser. Macbook M1, latest rstudio version. I use rstudio to compile python files.